# How can I build a debug version of Winlibs, or just libwinpthread.dll?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mingw

I'm reading "Threadtime" by Norton and Dipasquale.  Their exercises use pthreads.  I'm able to build and run them using Visual Studio, Cmake, and Winlibs (MinGW-64).

However, my breakpoints aren't hit when I debug, as the Winlibs binaries are built in release mode.  It seems like libwinpthread-1.dll is my specific problem.

So now I'm trying to rebuild libwinpthread-1.dll in debug mode, and I'm totally lost. Do I need to rebuild all of Mingw-64?  The entire toolchain?  Or just libwinpthread-1.dll somehow?

Or could anyone recommend a good book to learn multithreading with the Win32 API?

I just want to learn multithreading with something I can use on windows, and step through the program to see when threads are created, destroyed, etc.

Comment: Why do you need to debug the threading library dll?

Comment: @ssbssa I don't think I need to anymore...  I'm getting the impression that I can't do that in visual studio with a program compiled with gcc.  Visual Studio tells me that my breakpoints "will not currently be hit. There are no symbols loaded for this document"

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio doesn't understand the debug info of gcc compiled programs.

Comment: @ssbssa That definitely explains a lot.  I ended up getting a trial for VisualGDB.  Thanks!

https://visualgdb.com/